# Setting the EndDate of one datePicker on selection from another calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 inline calendars. When I select a date from the dtFrm calendar it sets the date on the dtTo calendar as expected. I just cant seem to set the EndDate of the dtTo calendar.

Anyone manage to solve this one?

```
    using:jquery.datePicker.min-2.1.2.js

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $('.dtFrm').datePicker({ inline: true })
                .bind(
                'dateSelected',
                function(e, selectedDate, $td) {
                    $('.dtTo').dpSetSelected(selectedDate.addDays(10).asString());//works
                    $('.dtTo').dpSetEndDate(selectedDate.addDays(11).asString());//doesnt work
                }
            );
            $('.dtTo').datePicker({ inline: true });
    });
    </script>

<div class="dtFrm" style="float:left"></div>
<div class="dtTo" style="float:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen my example showing how to do this? You can find it here:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerStartEnd.html

I'm not sure why this isn't working in your case. I notice you say you are using jquery.datePicker.min-2.1.2.js - this is actually very old code (although it is the latest release) - please grab the latest code from my website or svn.

Comment: Howzit vitch

Tried what u suggested. Used latest revision:
http://jquery-datepicker.googlecode.com/svn-history/r98/trunk/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js

yet the problem still persists